# Is it possible to abstract away a sealed Attribute with repetitive parameters?

Tags: c#, attributes

In my codebase, there is an attribute that appears many times with the **same arguments** being supplied.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
```

I would like to **simplify** this attribute to something like:

```
[User32Attribute] // Or perhaps a better name
```

I attempted to achieve this using **inheritance**, but I was unable because the `DllImportAttribute` class is **sealed**.

Here's what I attempted:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class User32Attribute : DllImportAttribute {
    public User32Attribute() : base("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true) {}
}
```

This, of course, failed with:

```
error CS0509: `User32Attribute': cannot derive from sealed type `System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute'
```

Is there something I can do to **abstract away the repetitive nature** of this attribute?

Comment: not likely... you could always write a Roslyn tool.

Comment: It is sealed because it is one of the few attributes that actually affect how the runtime operates (loading DLL's). It is unlikely that the runtime would understand your derived classes even if you could do that.

Comment: That's unfortunate. Looks like I'll need to write a mini pre-processor.

Comment: Exactly how many CTRL-C CTRL-V keystrokes do you think a preprocessor will save, vs the cost of writing and maintaining a tool? A tool that imposes the additional cost that now readers of your code need to understand the transformation imposed by the tool?

Comment: @EricLippert I get that, but I'd rather optimise my code for readability. My amount of duplication isn't _that_ large (certainly not large enough to warrant writing a fancy tool), but I'm sure someone might have a lot more.

Comment: @EricLippert If I just add a `sed` call to my makefile, nobody will even notice ;)

Comment: @byxor: They'll notice when the syntax highlighter gets confused.  If you cheat by adding a class and killing it via the preprocessor, you run the risk of the code compiling when run with that step skipped (though as long as the custom class is wrapped in a `#IF DEBUG`, it won't make it into production).   Personally, I prefer to mitigate the copy/pasting by sticking all the DLL Imports into special internal interop class.  Microsoft does the same thing in the Framework (`Win32Native`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, no, not without creating additional preprocessor tools, which defeats the entire purpose of "being simpler".

Comment: That makes sense. Simpler for me to maintain, but not simpler for other users to maintain.